# Dependency property changed callback not firing

Tags: wpf, properties, dependencies, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a control(DateRangeSelector) that registers a dependency property and its callback(TodayDateChanged) as per the below code:

DateRangeSelector.cs:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TodayDateProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("TodayDate", typeof(bool),
                            typeof(DateRangeSelectorControl),
                            new PropertyMetadata(true, TodayDateChanged));

private static void TodayDateChanged(DependencyObject d,
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    ((DateRangeSelectorControl)d).TodayDateChanged(); 
}

public bool TodayDate { 
    get { return (bool)GetValue(TodayDateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TodayDateProperty, value); } 
}
```

This control is being used in another XAML(ActivityListMenuControlView.xaml) as:

```
<DateRangeSelector:DateRangeSelectorControl x:Name="DateRangeSelector"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_TaskListDateRangeSelector"
                                            DateRangeUpdatedCmd="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionUpdatedCommand}"
                                            FontSize="{StaticResource TaskListMenuFontSize}"
                                            RangeOptions="{Binding Path=DateRangeSelectionOptions,
                                                                   Mode=OneTime}"
                                            SelectedDateRange="{Binding Path=SelectedRange,
                                                                        Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowFilterOptions,
                                                                 Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"
                                            TodayDate="{Binding TodayDate, ElementName=DateRangeSelector}" />
```

Note that DateRangeSelector's dependency property wrapper "TodayDate" is binded to and exposed through another property similaryly named "TodayDate" in view model(ActivityListMenuControlViewModel).
Here is the view model code:

```
private bool m_UpdateTodayDate; 
public bool TodayDate
{
    get { return m_UpdateTodayDate; }
    set 
    {
        m_UpdateTodayDate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TodayDate");
    } 
}
```

Now finally in another view model this property is assigned the same value each time:
ActivityListContainerViewModel.cs:

```
private void RefreshModule(bool updateDateRangeSelectorCtrl)
{
    //"Today" filter date changed: Update DateRangeSelector
    if (updateDateRangeSelectorCtrl)
    {
        m_MenuControlViewModel.TodayDate = true;
    }
}
```

Issue: Property changed callback "TodayDateChanged" in DateRangeSelector never got fired.
I debugged the code but the control never hit this callback.

Am i doing anything wrong in the code?

UPDATE:
As per comment from "franssu" i have changed my bindings as below:

```
<DateRangeSelector:DateRangeSelectorControl x:Name="DateRangeSelector" DataContext="MenuControlViewModel"                                     TodayDate="{Binding TodayDate,Mode=TwoWay}"                            />
```

Still no luck! No callback hit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DateRangeSelector:DateRangeSelectorControl x:Name="DateRangeSelector"
[...]
TodayDate="{Binding TodayDate, ElementName=DateRangeSelector}" />
```

You're binding the property to itself, i.e. the property of the control, not the VM's.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet as to how it should be?

Comment: How is `TodayDate` different from the other properties you have bound, such as `DateRangeSelectionOptions`, `SelectedRange` and `ShowFilterOptions` ?

Answer (score -2):

Always register your DP in static constructor of your class.